# Read Metamask Firefox vault binary file

Tags: metamask, wallets

I have a problem with Metamask Firefox. Mine is broken. Only white screen when I open Metamask.
I forgot to save the seed phrase. The only thing I have is the Metamask storage addons file on my Firefox profile.
This is a binary file. I tried to open the file and managed to find my data vault details. But there are some strange characters.
Please help me get my Metamask wallet again.

I can give you $500 if you can help me solve this issue.

binary hex file

```
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
```

[image: Open with EmEditor]

[image: Decrypt hex with python3]

Comment: Where did you find this file ? I lost the key of my sub accounts after reinstalling metamask. Hoping to also recover them using vault decryptor/

Comment: I'm having the same issue with this white screen and it's giving me serious anxiety. Can you please walk me through the same steps that you had gone through to recover the vault files and to decrypt? I've tried many things and struggling to get this working.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [MetaMask vault decryptor tool](https://metamask.github.io/vault-decryptor/) to decrypt your vault. Simply copy the contents of the file in the vault data field, enter your password, and click on "Decrypt". You should be able to see your decrypted vault data (including the seed).

You can find instructions for using the vault decryptor here: https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018766351%C2%A0

Note that, even though your vault file is encrypted, it's a *really* bad idea to ever paste your vault contents on any website. Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to remove it from StackExchange (it will still be in the history), so as soon as you get access to your vault, you should move all the funds in there to a new address (generated from a different seed phrase).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a post describing the process that led me to recover my wallet and i think you could use it to recover yours in a similar way. Ypu already have the file so i think you can skip to the last step where you decompress the data with snappy. After that you should be able to use the vault decryptor tool

https://medium.com/@rubenfb14/lost-metamask-wallet-the-forensic-way-c1871c3768f3

Answer (score 0):

if you just copy the files and paste them on a different browser extension or new one it'll just let you enter your password and access.
Note i'm having troubles doing this from mozilla to mozilla atm, works from chrome to chromium

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script that can recover the Vault data from the Firefox Metamask extension's .sqlite file.

The .sqlite files of firefox extensions contain a table called 'object_data' which contains a snappy-compressed key-value data structure. This data structure is encoded using a format seemingly only used by firefox for this one purpose.

Credit to this guy for figuring that out and writing the code to decode that data structure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59923297

I'm just applying this to the Metamask extension specifically.

You can find my script and instructions here: https://github.com/JesseBusman/FirefoxMetamaskWalletSeedRecovery